# How to get the category name from an id product in woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am creating a e-commerce website using woo commerce. I am struggling with a code that how to display the category name of the product using category id in woocommerce?.

In wordpress its easy to display the category name by id as `get_the_category_by_id(3)`. So that it display the name of the id 3.

By the same way how to display the category name by id in woocommerce?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try this function to get product category name

```
function get_product_category_by_id( $category_id ) {
    $term = get_term_by( 'id', $category_id, 'product_cat', 'ARRAY_A' );
    return $term['name'];
}
$product_category = get_product_category_by_id( $your_category_id );
```

Hope this will be useful.

Comment: wow super. working greatly. Thank you very much Ratnakar.. Thank you so much. I was struggling this for more than 2 days. Thank you once again..

Answer (score 8):

you can use something like this

```
$product_cats = wp_get_post_terms( your_id, 'product_cat' );
```

Please, let me know whether it helps.

```
print_r($product_cats);
```

Comment: i have used your code. but it doesnot seems to be work.

Comment: can you please print the output by print_r($product_cats); and let me what is the output..

Comment: do you have product id instead of category id?

Comment: if you can use the product id in the given function then you get all the details of the category..

Comment: Hi , its working but getting only one category , how can I get all the categories associated with that product ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use wp_get_post_terms to get category id of any product like this :

```
$term_list = wp_get_post_terms($product_id, 'product_cat', array('fields' => 'ids'));
```

I am just fetching id's of categories assigned to the particular product, You can fetch name also.

Hope this will be useful.