# Can't get category object in some templates of WooCommerce

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, woocommerce, categories

I'm using `get_category()` to get the category object by its ID. Here **`category 39`** is child of **`category 37`**. For example,

```
Courses (37) 
    - Programming (39)
```

My problem is that, if I use `get_category(37 or 39)` in `functions.php` BOTH will return `null`. If I use `get_category(37 or 39)` in `single-product.php` 37 (the root category) will return null. If I use this same call in `add-to-cart/simple.php` both will return an Object.

WooCommerce functions will be called first, and then `single-product.php` and then `add-to-cart/simple.php` templates.

What is happening?
Why does it work depending on the file?

---

@edit

```
get_term( 37, 'category' );
```

seems to fail as well

---

> @edit 13/7 - **The correct working solution**
>
> I managed to solve this issue before reading the answers with:
>
> ```
> $category = get_term_by('id', $category_id, 'product_cat');
> ```

References:

- [Function get_term_by()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_term_by/)
- [Show category list with titles](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/show-category-list-with-titles)
- [How to get the category name from an id product in woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22838939/how-to-get-the-category-name-from-an-id-product-in-woocommerce/22844327#22844327)

Comment: no, I will update it. i meant one or another. if I use 37 or 39, the term is only accessible in some files, but is not in some others. I have no idea why

Comment: Oh. So you call it with one value and then, you call it a different time, with the other value

Comment: that's what i am doing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use [**`get_category()`**](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_categories/) or [**`get_term()`**](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_terms/) directly with an ID everywhere. You need to use more arguments listed [**in here**](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_terms/) *(see the example below)*. On the templates, I think that also it depends on the displayed products (If they have this category or subcategory).

> To retrieve the desired **category object** you will need to do it by **category slug** and you will use [**`get_category_by_slug('the_slug')`**](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_category_by_slug) instead. Then you can retrieve the ID with:
>
> ```
> $idObj = get_category_by_slug('my_category_slug'); 
> $id = $idObj->term_id;
> ```

Others useful WordPress functions:
To retrieve category name based on category ID you will need to use [**`get_the_category_by_ID()`**](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_category_by_id/).
You can retrieve also the ID by **category name** and you will use [**`get_cat_ID( 'cat_name' )`**](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_cat_ID).

---

**Listing Product categories and subcategories with [`get_category()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_categories/) *(example)*:**

Here it is an example of a function based on [**this thread**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21009516/get-categories-from-wordpress-woocommerce/21012252#21012252), that will list all products categories and subcategories ***(everywhere)***:

```
function products_cats_subcats(){
    $taxonomy     = 'product_cat';
    $orderby      = 'name';
    $show_count   = 0;      // 1 for yes, 0 for no
    $pad_counts   = 0;      // 1 for yes, 0 for no
    $hierarchical = 1;      // 1 for yes, 0 for no
    $title        = '';
    $empty        = 0;

    $args = array(
        'taxonomy'     => $taxonomy,
        'orderby'      => $orderby,
        'show_count'   => $show_count,
        'pad_counts'   => $pad_counts,
        'hierarchical' => $hierarchical,
        'title_li'     => $title,
        'hide_empty'   => $empty
    );
    $all_categories = get_categories( $args );
    echo '<ul>';
    foreach ($all_categories as $cat) {
        if($cat->category_parent == 0) {
            $category_id = $cat->term_id;
            echo '<li><a href="'. get_term_link($cat->slug, 'product_cat') .'">'. $cat->name .'</a></li>';

            $args2 = array(
                'taxonomy'     => $taxonomy,
                'child_of'     => 0,
                'parent'       => $category_id,
                'orderby'      => $orderby,
                'show_count'   => $show_count,
                'pad_counts'   => $pad_counts,
                'hierarchical' => $hierarchical,
                'title_li'     => $title,
                'hide_empty'   => $empty
            );
            $sub_cats = get_categories( $args2 );
            echo '<ol>';
            if($sub_cats) {
                foreach($sub_cats as $sub_category) {
                    echo  '<li><a href="'. get_term_link($sub_category->slug, 'product_cat') .'">' . $sub_category->name .'</a></li>';
                }
            }
            echo '</ol>';
        }
    }
    echo '</ul>';
}
```

To use it just put it where you want: **`<?php products_cats_subcats() ;?>`**

That will display all your categories and subcategories hierarchically ordered by **Name**, with the corresponding link for each category or subcategory.

---

> Then you can also use [get_term_by()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_term_by) to get the category name or slug:
>
> ```
> $term = get_term_by('id', $term_id, 'product_cat', 'ARRAY_A');
>
> $term['name']; //get the WC category name
> $term['slug']; //get the WC category slug
> ```

---

Then now you will be able to build your own functions, to feet your needs…

---

Reference:

- [Get categories from Wordpress Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21009516/get-categories-from-wordpress-woocommerce/21012252#21012252)
- [Code Reference > Functions > get_categories()*](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_categories/)
- [Code Reference > Functions > get_terms() (and all optional arguments)*](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_terms/)
- [Code Reference > Function get_term_by()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_term_by)

Comment: the problem with get_the_category_by_ID is that it retuns only the name of the category. The fact that we can't use this function `get_category` in some templates in the same instance of Wordpress, but we can in some others seems odd to me. I mean, I thought it should find the category in the database and this would be independent of template or anything else..