# WooCommerce get category slug - Undefined property notice with a function

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, categories, product

I use this function to convert the woocommerce category id into a category slug

```
function woocommerceCategorySlug($id){
    $term = get_term( $id, 'product_cat' );
    return $term->slug;       
}
```

This is working, but the problem is that i'm getting a notice

> ```
> Notice: Undefined property: WP_Error::$slug
> ```

Is there a way to avoid this notice?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The working solution for this is to use WordPress native function **`get_term_by()`** and to transpose it in your code this way:

```
function woocommerceCategorySlug( $id ){
    $term = get_term_by('id', $id, 'product_cat', 'ARRAY_A');
    return $term['slug'];       
}
```

Reference:

- [Code Reference > Function get_term_by()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_term_by)
- [Can't get category object in some templates of WooCommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38288298/cant-get-category-object-in-some-templates-of-woocommerce/38291115#38291115)

Answer (score 2):

The [`get_term()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_term) function could return a [WP_Error](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Error) object if the term wasn't found, which is exactly the problem reported by the error you cited.

While the answer submitted by @LoicTheAztec works, the most direct approach might be to bake in some [defensive programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defensive_programming).  Here are a couple of ways:

#### Option 1

```
function woocommerceCategorySlug( $id )
{
    $term = get_term( $id, 'product_cat' );

    if( is_wp_error( $term ) || !is_object( $term ) || !property_exists( $term, 'slug' ) )
        return null;

    return $term->slug;
}
```

Now, if `get_term()` returns a `WP_Error` object, or not an object at all, or the expected object doesn't have a 'slug' property, then return null.  Otherwise, return the slug.

#### Option 2

Alternatively, you could have the `get_term()` function return the result as an associative array and simplify the checks a bit:

```
function woocommerceCategorySlug( $id )
{
    $term = get_term( $id, 'product_cat', ARRAY_A );

    return isset( $term['slug'] ) ? $term['slug'] : null;
}
```

In this version, `isset()` serves a dual purpose: to see if the slug exists in the expected array, or fail silently if `$term` isn't an array in the first place.